# I don't understand transformer power ratings

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer

I'm befuddled.  I have a wall wart power supply that supplies 65W (it's for an Intel NUC).  I'm interested in building my own power supply that will put out... several different voltages and currents.  So I go to mouser.com and try to find an appropriate transformer.  I plug in several different power ratings.  And then the trouble starts.  They all cost much more than I expect.  And, I notice, they're huge.  So I search for something that ought to be in my NUC's power supply.  What I find for 75VA is about 8-10 times larger than the entire NUC supply.  And it costs twice what the whole NUC supply costs.  So I cut open an unused wall wart.  Yes, it has a transformer.  No markings on it at all.  So now I'm wondering whether I know what a power rating on a transformer is.  If I believe mouser.com, then the NUC's transformer (if it has one) is wildly undersized.  If I believe the NUC, then mouser's are wildly oversized.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your wall wart is a switching power supply, which can use a high-frequency transformer. In search for a transformer for your own design, you aere looking for a 50/60 Hz transformer, which needs to be much larger and (hence) more expensive.

A transformer roughly works by converting the input electrical energy to magnetic energy, and then converting that to electrical energy again, but at the output voltage. The size of the core of a transformer must be able to contain the magnetic field. At 50/60 Hz this happens 50 or 60 times each second. In a high-frequency switched power supply this happens for instance at 10 kHz (200 times more often than at 50 Hz), so a smaller core can be used to transfer the same amount of power.

I would advise you NOT to try and build your own switching power supply, because your situation requires isolation and a reasonble power, which makes it a specialists project.

As a side note, it is a sad fact of life that the compontes you can find in a mass produced product will together cost much more than the product itself.